# Upgrade from Hibernate 5.2.5.final to 5.2.8.final duplicate primary key issue

Tags: hibernate, duplicates, upgrade, one-to-one

We have two entities, A and B, and A has a B which is OneToOne mapping by b_id.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "IdOrGenerated")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "IdOrGenerated", strategy = "com.xxx.yyy.UseIdOrGenerate")
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String  id;  

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
  private B b;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "IdOrGenerated")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "IdOrGenerated", strategy = "com.xxx.yyy.UseIdOrGenerate")
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String  id;  

  private String name;
}
```

The Database schema:

A {id, b_id}; PK: id; FK_B_ID -> table B'id
B {id, name}; PK: id;

It works for Hibernate 5.2.5.final. When we tried to upgrade to 5.2.8.final, got error: Duplicate entry '414b017c-c014-4344-99af-595f9a80a388' for key 'PRIMARY'.

Hibernate seems set the b_id to A twice.

We tried if we map B to A using a_id on the B table, it is ok for Hibernate 5.2.8.final

To summary for Hibernate 5.2.8.final:
1. one-to-one child is mapped to its parent by the parent id on the child table, which is ok;
2. one-to-one child is mapped to its parent by the child id on the parent table, which causes duplicate id for the child's primary key.

Both of above cases works for Hibernate 5.2.5.final.

Any ideas about how to make the case 2 work for Hibernate 5.2.8.final? At this moment, we do not want to change our database schema.

Thanks, Jing

Comment: We found out the root cause is the AbstractProducedQuery.doList() returns empty collection when query's maxResult is zero in 5.2.8.final, but ignores maxResult zero in 5.2.5. 
When populating FK for some entity, query returns null in 5.2.8.final, which causes the errors. After we fix our query bug which does not set maxResult zero, then upgrade is fine.